# How to read a file from Django MEDIA_ROOT and let the user download it in the front-end?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I have a view as follows:

```
def import_data(request):
    if request.method == "GET::
        column_names = network_asset._meta.fields #network_asset is the Model name
        column_names = [x.name for x in column_names]
        with open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'excel_templates', 'template.csv'), 'w+', newline = '') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(column_names)
```

Now, I want to pass in the file as context to the HTML page and download it using an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="{{ myfile }}" download > Download {{ myfile }}</a>
```

My settings.py has

```
# Media files (Excel templates, downloadable files)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/')
MEDIA_URL  = '/media/'
```

Urls.py has

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^network/',include('network.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by pure luck and trial-error method.
I need to pass in the `url` to the context. Needed to put this in one of the views

```
    file_path = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'excel_templates')
    file_name = 'template.csv'
    myfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(file_path)]
    context = {}
    context['myfiles'] = myfiles
    file_name = context.get('myfiles')[0]
        
    myfile_url = os.path.join(MEDIA_URL,'excel_templates', file_name)
        
    return render(request,'network/import_data.html', context = {
            'myfile_url':myfile_url
    })
```